# does setMouseCallback method not work with tkinter?

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am working on Slideshow application.
Basically this shows all the pictures in a certain directory in every 5 seconds, and if you click the picture changes.
It had worked so well until I mixed it with `tkinter`.
It seems like my `setMouseCallback` method doesn't work anymore...
Any helps?

```
import os
import cv2
import random
import tkinter as tk



root = tk.Tk()

mouseClickChecker=1

def func():
    
    def clickevent(event,x,y,flags,param):
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            global mouseClickChecker
            mouseClickChecker=2
    
    path = "./"

    file_list = os.listdir(path)

    file_list_jpg = [file for file in file_list if file.endswith('.jpg')]
    file_list_JPG = [file for file in file_list if file.endswith('.JPG')]
    file_list_jpeg = [file for file in file_list if file.endswith('.jpeg')]
    file_list_PNG= [file for file in file_list if file.endswith('.PNG')]
    file_list_png=[file for file in file_list if file.endswith('.png')]

    list_in_list = [file_list_jpg, file_list_PNG, file_list_JPG, file_list_jpeg,file_list_png]
    final_list = sum(list_in_list,[])

    logoPlayChecker=1

    while(True):

        random.shuffle(final_list)

        final_list[0]='logo.jpg'

        real_final_list=[]
    
        for v in final_list:
            if v not in real_final_list:
                real_final_list.append(v)
            
        print(real_final_list)
    
        for i in real_final_list:
            mouseClickChecker=1
            img = cv2.imread(i)
            
            winname = "slidshow"
            
            cv2.namedWindow(winname, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN) ##WINDOW_NORMAL
            cv2.setWindowProperty(winname, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
            cv2.imshow(winname, img)

            if logoPlayChecker == 1:
                cv2.waitKey(3500)
                logoPlayChecker=2
            else:
                cv2.waitKey(100)

                for i in range(50):
                    
                    cv2.setMouseCallback(winname, clickevent)

                    if mouseClickChecker==2:
                        print(mouseClickChecker)
                        break
                    else:
                        mouseClickChecker=1
                        print(mouseClickChecker)
                        cv2.waitKey(100)

        logoPlayChecker=1


label = tk.Label(root, text='push button')

label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text = 'push!', command = func)

button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter has it's own method of capturing button presses and it is probably blocking the cv2 callback.

You can register a call back for a button press in tkinter using

```
root.bind("<Button-1>", nameOfCallbackFunction)
```

Worth noting that tkinter does not work with infinite while loops like you have defined inside `func`

To resolve this, I'd suggest moving the code from the loop to a new function which is called when you click.

You should also remove/replace any `waitKey` calls. These will block tkinter and prevent it from responding to button presses.